# How to manipulate one line at a time?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I use the following code:

```
with open('examplefile.csv') as tst:
    for line in tst:
        x = line
        print(x)
```

I see 5 columns and numerous rows.

How do I take one row at a time and set variables to each item in a row?

Answer (score 4):

The for loop already takes one line at a time

Split the line into a list.

Assuming comma is the delimiter, this assigns variables to each column

```
x, y, z, a, b = line.split(',')
print(x)
```

*This also assumes you don't have nested commas within columns*

For a better solution please see the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)

Note: Pandas has more useful functions for CSV manipulation

Comment: This is the right way of doing it.

Comment: The better way is using a DictReader, though https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader

Comment: Does this work for cell entries escaped by quotes with commas inside? For instance line ="\"City\", \"Austin, TX\"".  Expected 2 cells.

Comment: @MFisher I appreciate you  using my current city, but does the question show such data?

Comment: @cricket_007 perhaps you aren't the only SO user in Austin?

Comment: I guess we are neighbors then. :) The question is general. I don't consider myself a "python guy" so I'm curious. This is probably why I'd advise using the built in functions instead of splitting on a comma. I've been burned doing this (splitting on commas) in production code (not python).

Comment: @MFisher I think it's a general rule across all languages that if you split a single character from a string, there's no special logic to account for escaped instances of that character. In which case, the `csv` module is better.

Answer (score 3):

Use the csv module:

```
import csv
with open('examplefile.csv') as tst:
    reader = csv.reader(tst, delimiter=',')
    for line in reader:
        # line is a delimiter-delimited line in your file
```

Hope that helps.